# Cordova storage working on android and dev ios but not on other ios devices

Tags: ios, cordova

We successfully built and deployed a cordova application utilizing the localstorage to persist login data.

This application works as debug build on android and our development iphone (iphone 6s running latest ios 14) but customers reported after rollout that data doesn't get stored (not even while app is running) on ios devices.

We then switched to the codova native storage plugin (https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage), again working on our devices but not on other customers devices. (The app store build also works on our dev iphone)

Does anyone know what could be the difference between our device and all others?

Our last idea is to use file storage.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, we were having cors - issues as ios handles the origin different than android